# Extracting shell script from parameterised Hudson job

Tags: linux, bash, hudson

I have a [parameterised Hudson job](http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Parameterized+Build), used for some [AWS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amazon_Web_Services) deployment stuff, which in one build step runs certain shell commands.

However, that script has become sufficiently complicated that I want to "extract" it from Hudson to a separate script file, so that it can easily be versioned properly. The Hudson job would then simply update from VCS and execute the external script file.

My **main question** is about passing parameters to the script. I have a Hudson parameter named `AMI_ID` and a few others. The script references those params as if they were environment variables:

```
echo "Using AMI $AMI_ID and type $TYPE"
```

Now, this works fine inside Hudson, but not if Hudson calls an external script. Could I somehow make Hudson set the params as environment variables so that I don't need to change the script? Or is my best option to alter the script to take command line parameters (and possibly assign those to named variables for readability: `ami_id=$1; type=$2; ...` )?

I tried something like this but the script doesn't get correctly replaced values:

```
export AMI_ID=$AMI_ID
export TYPE=$TYPE
external-script.sh # this tries to use e.g. $AMI_ID
```

**Bonus question**: when the script is inside Hudson, the "console output" will contain both the executed commands and their output. This is extremely useful for debugging when something goes wrong with a build! For example, here the line starting with "+" is part of the script and the following line its output:

```
+ ec2-associate-address -K pk.pem -C cert.pem 77.125.116.139 -i i-aa3487fd
ADDRESS 77.125.116.139  i-aa3487fd
```

When calling an external script, Hudson output will only contain the latter line, making debugging harder. I could `cat` the script file to stdout before running it, but that's not optimal either. In effect, I'd like a kind of DOS-style "**echo on**" for the script which I'm calling from Hudson - anyone know a trick to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It shouldn't be necessary to do `export var=$var` - try using just `export var`. However, try:

```
AMI_ID=$AMI_ID TYPE=$TYPE external-script.sh
```

all on one line.

To answer your second question, try using the `-x` option of Bash. In your external script, add it to your shebang:

```
#!/bin/bash -x
```

or surround sections of the script you want traced with:

```
set -x
do_stuff
more_stuff
set +x
```

Comment: Excellent, thanks! Both questions solved. Especially bash tracing solution is elegant - I was hoping there'd be something exactly like this (and indeed I could have deducted it from how Hudson itself runs its scripts: `/bin/sh -xe /tmp/hudson[...].sh` :-).